# Перебор массива по принципу "затухающего маятника"

Tags: java, циклы

Есть массив с рандомным количеством элементов (четным/нечетным). Допустим, `50 <  размер массива < 100`.
Как вывести все элементы массива по одному по принципу "затухающего маятника", а именно: если 85, то:

```
1, 85, 2, 84, 3, 83...
```

И так до последнего в середине. При этом требуется высчитывать разницу между `1` и `85`, `2` и `84` и т.д. для привязки к задержке потока (поток реализовывать не нужно). При отсутствии пары у последнего элемента разницу не учитывать.

Comment: Куда вывести все элементы массива? На экран, или в новый массив, или куда-то ещё? В какой момент нужно высчитывать разницу между парами и куда её сохранять? И в чём, собственно, возникла проблема при решении у вас?

Comment: @Regent: на экран, там свяжу потом, разницу так же. Две фигуры движутся навстречу друг другу, длина рандомная.

Comment: А числа в массиве идут подряд от `0` до `длина - 1`, или же они случайные?

Comment: @Regent подряд, а там уже работать с началом и концом

Comment: Кстати, выборка `50, 100, 49, 99, 48, 98` не похожа на затухающий маятник, ибо между элементами всегда ровно 49 элементов. Либо должно быть `1, 100, 2, 99, 3, 98`, либо вы подобрали неправильное сравнение.

Comment: @Regent: а ну да, вы правы, там же рандомное число в любом случае от одного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учетом особой обработки среднего элемента в массиве нечётной длины:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] values = new int[85];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (values.length + 1) / 2; i++)
    {
        int first = values[i];
        System.out.print(first + " ");
        if (2 * (i + 1) <= values.length)
        {
            int second = values[values.length - i - 1];
            System.out.print(second + " " + (first - second));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам. Ваше решение предельно помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте, вот так:

```
int[] array = new int[100];

for (int i = 0, j = array.length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
     System.out.println(i + ":" + j + " = " + (jarray[j] - iarray[i]));
```

Comment: А если в массиве числа идут не подряд и не от `0` до `length - 1`? Потому что в вашем варианте массив вообще не нужен: можно было бы просто `j = 99` сделать и всё.

Comment: стоит тогда и `i + ":" + j` заменить на `array[i] + ":" + array[j]`.

Comment: А ещё есть занятный момент по поводу отсутствия пары у среднего элемента в массиве нечетной длины: по идее, по условию и его пару не нужно выводить, и разницу.

Comment: @Artem Konovalov:  [ваш пример](http://ideone.com/woQuny). Разница по нулям. Но все равно спасибо большое, бодался с двумя циклами.

Comment: @TimurVI очевидно что там разница будет 0, массив пустой. его нужно заполнять. Но это вы сами я думаю сможете сделать.

Comment: предыдущий ваш ответ был ближе к решению. В этом ответе отразилась непонятая мною последовательность вывода. @Regent указал.